# Python docx cannot able to read bullet points from word(.docx)

Tags: python-3.x, python-docx

Below is the code snippet written to read the contents of the word file using docx lib but the docx lib doesn't support to capture the bullet points while reading from the document

```
from docx import Document
import os

document = Document('book1.docx')
for p in document.paragraphs:
    print(p.text)
```

Is there any inbuilt-function or library available to read contents of the docx file with bullet points?

Comment: Does this help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51829366/bullet-lists-in-python-docx

Comment: yes,I have tried this too it shows style is not defined