# Getting the List Numbers of List Items in docx file using Python-Docx

Tags: python, python-3.x, ms-word, python-docx

When I am accessing paragraph text it does not include the numbering in a list.

Current code:

```
document = Document("C:/Foo.docx")
for p in document.paragraphs:
     print(p.text)
```

List in docx file:

[image: Numbered List]

I am expecting: 
(1) The naturalization of both ... 
(2) The naturalization of the ... 
(3) The naturalization of the ...

What I get: 
The naturalization of both ... 
The naturalization of the ... 
The naturalization of the ...

Upon checking the XML of the document, the list numbers are stored in w:abstructNum but I have no idea how to access them or connect them to the proper list item.
How can I access the number for each list item in python-docx so they could be included in my output?
Is there a way also to determine the proper nesting of these lists using python-docx?

Comment: This is a non-trivial challenge. Have you seen this SO response? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51829366/bullet-lists-in-python-docx

Comment: Thanks @scanny. I will look into this and see if I can work it out. Thank you for your work on python-docx, it helped a lot on my current project.

Comment: Could you share (a relevant part of) your *.docx* file?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

According to [[ReadThedocs.Python-DocX]: Style-related objects - _NumberingStyle objects](https://python-docx.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/style.html#numberingstyle-objects), this functionality is not implemented **yet**. 
The alternative (at least one of them) [[PyPI]: docx2python](https://pypi.org/project/docx2python) is kind of poor handling these elements (mainly because it returns everything converted to strings).

So, a solution would be to parse the *XML* files manually - discovered how empirically, working on this very example. A good documentation place is [Office Open XML](http://officeopenxml.com) (I don't know whether it's a standard followed by all the tools that deal with *.docx* files (especially *MS Word*)):

- Get each paragraph (***w:p*** node) from *word/document.xml*

  - Check whether it's a numbered item (it has ***w:pPr*** -> ***w:numPr***) subnode
  - Get the number style *Id* and level: ***w:val*** attribute of ***w:numId*** and ***w:ilvl*** subnodes (of the node from previous bullet)
  - Match the 2 values with (in *word/numbering.xml*):

    - ***w:abstractNumId*** attribute of ***w:abstractNum*** node
    - ***w:ilvl*** attribute of ***w:lvl*** subnode

    and get the ***w:val*** attribute of the corresponding ***w:numFmt*** and ***w:lvlText*** subnodes (note that bullets are included as well, they can be discriminated based on the ***bullet*** value for aforementioned ***w:numFmt***'s attribute)

However that seems **extremely complex**, so I'm proposing a workaround (*gainarie*) that makes use of *docx2python*s partial support.

Test document (*sample.docx* - **created with  *LibreOffice***):

[image: Img0]

*code00.py*:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python

import sys
import docx
from docx2python import docx2python as dx2py


def ns_tag_name(node, name):
    if node.nsmap and node.prefix:
        return "{{{:s}}}{:s}".format(node.nsmap[node.prefix], name)
    return name


def descendants(node, desc_strs):
    if node is None:
        return []
    if not desc_strs:
        return [node]
    ret = {}
    for child_str in desc_strs[0]:
        for child in node.iterchildren(ns_tag_name(node, child_str)):
            descs = descendants(child, desc_strs[1:])
            if not descs:
                continue
            cd = ret.setdefault(child_str, [])
            if isinstance(descs, list):
                cd.extend(descs)
            else:
                cd.append(descs)
    return ret


def simplified_descendants(desc_dict):
    ret = []
    for vs in desc_dict.values():
        for v in vs:
            if isinstance(v, dict):
                ret.extend(simplified_descendants(v))
            else:
                ret.append(v)
    return ret


def process_list_data(attrs, dx2py_elem):
    #print(simplified_descendants(attrs))
    desc = simplified_descendants(attrs)[0]
    level = int(desc.attrib[ns_tag_name(desc, "val")])
    elem = [i for i in dx2py_elem[0].split("\t") if i][0]#.rstrip(")")
    return "    " * level + elem + " "


def main(*argv):
    fname = r"./sample.docx"
    docd = docx.Document(fname)
    docdpy = dx2py(fname)
    dr = docdpy.docx_reader
    #print(dr.files)  # !!! Check word/numbering.xml !!!
    docdpy_runs = docdpy.document_runs[0][0][0]
    if len(docd.paragraphs) != len(docdpy_runs):
        print("Lengths don't match. Abort")
        return -1
    subnode_tags = (("pPr",), ("numPr",), ("ilvl",))  # (("pPr",), ("numPr",), ("ilvl", "numId"))  # numId is for matching elements from word/numbering.xml
    for idx, (par, l) in enumerate(zip(docd.paragraphs, docdpy_runs)):
        #print(par.text, l)
        numbered_attrs = descendants(par._element, subnode_tags)
        #print(numbered_attrs)
        if numbered_attrs:
            print(process_list_data(numbered_attrs, l) + par.text)
        else:
            print(par.text)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    print("Python {:s} {:03d}bit on {:s}\n".format(" ".join(elem.strip() for elem in sys.version.split("\n")),
                                                   64 if sys.maxsize > 0x100000000 else 32, sys.platform))
    rc = main(*sys.argv[1:])
    print("\nDone.")
    sys.exit(rc)
```

**Output**:

> ```
> [cfati@CFATI-5510-0:e:\Work\Dev\StackOverflow\q066374154]> "e:\Work\Dev\VEnvs\py_pc064_03.09_test0\Scripts\python.exe" code00.py
> Python 3.9.9 (tags/v3.9.9:ccb0e6a, Nov 15 2021, 18:08:50) [MSC v.1929 64 bit (AMD64)] 064bit on win32
>
> Doc title
> doc subtitle
>
> heading1 text0
>
> Paragr0 line0
> Paragr0 line1
> Paragr0 line2
>
> space Paragr0 line3
> a) aa (numbered)
> heading1 text1
> Paragrx line0
> Paragrx line1
>         a)      w tabs Paragrx line2 (NOT numbered – just to mimic 1ax below)
>
> 1) paragrx 1x (numbered)
>     a) paragrx 1ax (numbered)
>         I) paragrx 1aIx (numbered)
>     b) paragrx 1bx (numbered)
> 2) paragrx 2x (numbered)
> 3) paragrx 3x (numbered)
>
> -- paragrx bullet 0
>     -- paragrx bullet 00
>
> paragxx text
>
> Done.
> ```

**Notes**:

- Only nodes from *word/document.xml* are processed (via paragraph's *_element* (*LXML* node) attribute)
- Some list attributes are not captured (due to *docx2python*'s limitations)
- This is far away from being robust
- *descendants*, *simplified_descendants* can be much simplified, but I wanted to keep the former as generic as possible (if functionality needs to be extended)

Comment: What does it mean if I get the ```lengths don't match``` output?

Comment: @Sven: Well it needs some more debugging. Obviously the 2 modules interpret the document differently.  I'm not sure what their versions are. For that particular (dummy) document that I created and the versions that I used at the time, things worked fine. I imagine that in the last year both modules evolved, and now things might be solved using just one of them.

Answer (score 3):

this worked for me, using the module `docx2python`

```
from docx2python import docx2python
document = docx2python("C:/input/MyDoc.docx")
print(document.body)
```

Answer (score 0):

There is another path which consists in converting the numbering to text in the first place. After which you can use `python-docx` as usual, without the hassle of handling them yourself.

Open the document in Word, open the Visual Basic editor (`F11`), open the immediate window (`ctrl-G`), type the following macro and press enter:

```
ActiveDocument.Range.ListFormat.ConvertNumbersToText
```

At this point, you can save the document and run it through `python-docx`.