# how to read the numbers in the start of the line from docx files in python?

Tags: python, docx2txt

Example for a docx text:

[image]

after running this block of code

```
dir_data ="some_dir"
import docx2txt
 for file in os.listdir(dir_data):  
    with open(os.path.join(dir_data,file), 'rb') as infile:
        with open(file[:-5]+'.txt', 'w', encoding='utf-8') as outfile:
            doc = docx2txt.process(infile)
            outfile.write(doc)
```

It return a txt file but the text is without the head number  - "Hello word"
and without a subclause number -"My name is max"

how to fix it?

Comment: Is it always the same format? Number period space text?

Comment: You can have numbers in the text itself.
There is a numbering library in Word that makes it impossible to read the docx file properly.

Is there any available solution to this?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "numbering library" is it a numbered list? Maybe this helps? https://stackoverflow.com/a/70764141/5640517

Comment: Yes it's called a numbered list but the function you gave me numbering the lines 
I have text that some lines don't have a number at the head of the line and there is a subclause 

1. hello world 
my name is max
1.1. this is the truth ....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to everybody!
I found the solution

```
import aspose.words as aw

# Load DOC file
doc = aw.Document(r"some_dir")

# Save DOC as TXT
doc.save("doc-to-text.txt")
```

Comment: not sure if undercover promo.... Edit: maybe, `pip install aspose-words` does work and is free, even if the returned string has `Evaluation Only. Created with Aspose.Words. Copyright 2003-2023 Aspose Pty Ltd`

Comment: Yeap I noticed but I couldn't make it work any other way.
I can assure you I do not promote any company.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with [docx2python](https://pypi.org/project/docx2python/)

```
from docx2python import docx2python

dir_data ="some_dir"
for file in os.listdir(dir_data):
    doc = docx2python(os.path.join(dir_data,file))
    with open('file.txt', 'a', encoding='utf-8') as outfile:
        outfile.write(doc.text.replace(')', '.'))
```

Comment: It fails to make the right subclause
1. hello world 
    1.1.my name is max

It returns 
1. Hello word

 1. My name is max

Answer (score 0):

I tested it, it works on my setup.

**Code:**

```
import os
from docx import Document

dir_data = "C:\\Users\\<username>\\Desktop\\test"  # test directory on Desktop

for file in os.listdir(dir_data):
    if file.endswith(".docx"):
        docx_path = os.path.join(dir_data, file)
        txt_path = os.path.splitext(docx_path)[0] + '.txt'

        document = Document(docx_path)
        with open(txt_path, 'w', encoding='utf-8') as outfile:
            for i, paragraph in enumerate(document.paragraphs, start=1):
                text = f"{i}. {paragraph.text.strip()}"
                if text:  # Ignore empty paragraphs
                    outfile.write(text + '\n')
```

**Output:**

[image]

Comment: doesn't work for subclause