# Extracting numbered lists from docx documents as they appear in the document (python 3.X)

Tags: python, text, docx, document

I have `.docx` documents that I need to parse, extracting numbered lists as they appear in the document. For example:
[image]

However, different approaches have not resulted in anything. What I've tried so far:

1. Using tools like `python-docx`. Does not extract lists at all.
2. Parsing the document `XML` directly. Fails when the `w:numId` value changes randomly inside a list, I suspect due to human error when creating the document... No idea how to handle this.
3. Using `pandoc` to convert the `.docx` to a string. Closest approach so far, yet does not keep the identical structure - output looks like this:
   [image]

   `extra_args=["--number-sections"]` does not change anything. I could parse the string after the conversion with a script, but I'm leaving that for a last-resort solution and instead hoping for a cleaner solution.

Any ideas on how to solve this? Seems like a trivial task, yet it has been driving me mad the last couple of days. Thank you in advance!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Getting the List Numbers of List Items in docx file using Python-Docx](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66374154/getting-the-list-numbers-of-list-items-in-docx-file-using-python-docx)

Comment: Also [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77214945/how-to-read-the-numbers-in-the-start-of-the-line-from-docx-files-in-python/77215637)

Comment: @Daviid thank you! I've tried the first post before, but `aspose-words` from the second post worked!

Answer (score 0):

`aspose-words` seems to extract lists correctly:) Thank you @Daviid !

```py
import aspose.words as aw

doc = aw.Document(FILEPATH)

#convert to .txt
doc.save(os.path.basename(FILEPATH)+".txt")

#read as string
docstr = open(os.path.basename(FILEPATH)+".txt", "r").read()
```