# Attribute that defines a paragraph is a bulleted list style in python-docx

Tags: python, python-docx

I'm working with a document that has a custom Style that has a custom bulleted list style applied to it. I need to be able to inspect this style and understand that it is a bulleted list. Is there a property of the style that would be associated with this? I've been looking at the the properties within the paragraph format like so:

```
document = Document('example.docx')
styles = document.styles
for style in style:
    print(dir(style.paragraph_format))
```

but none of these objects that I've looked at thus far make it clear that there's a bulleted list style. Is this information stored somewhere? As I said, the name of the style is custom and so isn't named as some built-in `List Bullet` style or anything like that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is currently no API support in `python-docx` for detecting this condition. You would need to inspect the XML of the style and you may need to walk through a few references as there is potentially some inheritance involved.

I'd recommend starting with a paragraph style you know has bullets applied and `print(style._element.xml)` and see what you can make out by way of an element is "number" in its name or whatever hints you can find.

I will tell you that list formatting is a complex matter in Word. You can probably find some other resources on search that may give clues, this one came up on a quick searh: [Bullet Lists in python-docx](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51829366/bullet-lists-in-python-docx)

Comment: Appreciate your help, @scanny. I did in fact run through some examples and for the ones I looked at, detecting the `numId` attribute was a decent clue as to whether I was working with some sort of list style. Understanding precisely what that value means in the context of the document is another matter, but perhaps not one that I need for my narrow use case. I appreciate you letting me know that there's no other obvious way.